# Using a Try / Catch in a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch, do-while, illegalargumentexception

I'm asking my user to input via regex format "ABC-1234" otherwise an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown. I would like to keep asking for the correct input (I'm thinking while or do while with a boolean variable set to false while input is incorrect...) how would I do that with a try / catch?

Here's what I have thus far. Thanks!

```
try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter id: ");
            String id = in.nextLine();

            Inventory i1 = new Inventory (id, "sally", 14, 2, 2);
            System.out.println(i1);

        } catch (Exception ex) {

             System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you need some kind of loop and you need some mechanism to break out of the loop on success. Supposing `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown from `Inventory` constructor, your solution can simply be:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        // ...
        Inventory i1 = new Inventory(id, "sally", 12, 2, 2);
        System.out.println(i1);
        break; // or return i1 if you enclose this snippet in a function
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // ...
    }
}
```